# What is the way to navigate to a new ViewModel with "back" navigation when using "standard" ChangePresentation Hints in MvvmCross?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

The scenario is pretty simple: let's imagine we are on Home page, and a user is logs out, so we should create a login page **one level lower in the NavigationStack** and just close (popup) currently active (Home) page.

So, can that be achieved **with out-of-box MvvmCross** functionality, or I still have to create a *Custom Presenter* and handle that logic manually?

*This is mostly related to Xamarin.Forms case, but in terms of MvvmCross it shouldn't matter.*

**UPD:** This is all about having a nice "disappearing" animation, like we have on iOS when the top view just slides to the right and the previous (in the navigation stack) view appears on the background.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to push over the stack, just pop using Close and then open the Login page, as shown:

```
Navigator.Close(this);
Navigator.Navigate<LoginViewModel>();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach wouldn't have nice animation of disappearing of existing view. (Like sliding to the right on iOS, for instance).
This is the core of the question.

Comment: Hmm what you are requesting would require to keep the Login page on the bottom of the stack at all times while you are logged in and accessing the app. And you generally don't want that behavior. You could use a page transition library to force that though. Or as a work around, you can hide the back button that comes up when you push the dashoard page over the login page.

Comment: Not really. On native platforms (actually, even with Xamarin.Forms and Custom Presenter) you can "insert" newly created page anywhere you want in the navigation stack sequence. The question was only about being able to do that with "out-of-the-box" features provided by MvvmCross (again, without creating a custom presenter).